# How to make a button with rounded corners, background image and text in android

Tags: java, android, image, button, text

I'm trying to create an android button whose text can be changed (to be able to internationalize the app easily), but at the same time have a background, and using rounded corners if possible.

So far, if I use a background image I can not get the corners to be round and vice versa.

The last thing I tried is to create these xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF404040" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="#FF6800" android:centerColor="#FF8000" android:endColor="#FF9700" android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF404040" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="#FF6800" android:centerColor="#FF8000" android:endColor="#FF9700" android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

and this button, but I can not put a background image:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="277dp" />
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a result similar to the [Morning Ritual button in this app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdxRR.png), for example, if that is a button, which I do not know either.

Comment: It's probably a cardview, check this https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CardView` or If you want to create `Button`, try this xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="5dp">
            <corners
                 android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                 android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
         </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourImage" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageButton, where **android:src** - image you need and **android:background** - rounded shape:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/roundedImageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/backgound"
            android:text="TEXT" 
            android:background="@drawable/roundedShape" />
```

Or CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"> 

     <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEXT"/>

   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do all of them dynamically just like this

```
 Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setText("Test");
 button.setBackground(getRoundRect());
```

and by getRoundRect() you can get rounded corner shape with the color and size you 
want

```
public Drawable getRoundRect() {
    RoundRectShape rectShape = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{
            10, 10, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 10, 10
    }, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(rectShape);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    return shapeDrawable;
}
```

or if you want to make gradient rounded corner shape you can easily use this code

```
 GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(10f);
    button.setBackground(gd);
```

all of my suggestion was for making a button by dynamic text and rounded corners and colors

good luck and have fun (;